# Flask request as json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, flask

I have 1 small program. I'm sending the request of json via CURL X POST and should get the answer.
The client code is:

```
curl -XPOST -d'{"animal":"cow", "sound":"moooo", "count": "3"}' 192.168.88.88:5000/test
```

The server code is:

```
import json
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name)

@app.route("/test", methods=['POST'])
def json_example():
  content = request.get_json(silent=True)
  animal = content["animal"]
  sound = content["sound"]
  count = str(content["count"])
  i=0
  res=''
  while i<int(count):
    temp = animal + "says " + sound +"\n"
    res = temp +res
    i = i + 1
  return res

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port = 5000)
```

If I'm running the request at postman and indicating that this is json type - then all is OK, but if I'm running it via curl - has an error (None type object isn't subscriptable)
Please advice, how to correct the code at server and indicate, that all responses will be type of json.

Thanks

Comment: `request.get_json(...)` returns `None` for your case. You should ask `if request.is_json` before calling `get_json()`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify `-H "Content-Type: application/json"` with the `curl` request. Alternatively you can use `request.form.values` if you don't specify header type for the request:

```sh
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -XPOST -d'{"animal":"cow", "sound":"moooo", "count": "3"}' 192.168.88.88:5000/test
```

For your `curl` request the `mimetype` given by `request.mimetype` is `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`